# Personal hotspot problem: "Set Up Personal Hotspot"

Tags: iphone, cellular-carriers, tethering

I am trying to enable my the hotspot from my iPhone 6. I am in the beta program (if that matters).

I am on Verizon.

Whenever I press, "Set Up Personal Hotspot" it brings up this message,

"To enable Personal Hotspot on this account, visit https://mobile.vzw.com/hybridClient/mvm/hotspot"

My brother is on the same plan, and his works great. Same iPhone. Meaning our Verizon account is set up for hotspots. (Also, I checked on our account settings, and it is enabled.)

I already rebooted the phone, and reset network settings.

Any ideas why it won't turn on a hotspot?

Comment: Have you tried going to the website your phone suggested?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently back when I had a flip phone I had asked that data usage be turned off. (So that I wouldn’t accidentally get charged when I pressed the “internet” button.)

One of those switches they turned off was the use of hotspot.

I called Verizon and they simply enabled the use of hotspots again.

Answer (score 0):

All iOS devices will turn on tethering when they get the go-ahead from the carrier. There isn't any other switch than the one you see.

You could try backing up the phone, erasing all content and settings and making sure it's not the OS, but it's almost certainly something you need someone to verify your carrier settings. Calling Verizon support would be my first step.